# list_dir returns timeout error when there are more than one file or directory erlang ssh_sftp

Tags: ssh, elixir, sftp

I use `ssh_sftp.list_dir` to get list of files & directories in a given path. It return list of child directories when there is only one directory or file inside the given path. But when there are more than one files/directories in the path, it returned `timeout`.
error.

Does anyone has any idea.

Comment: It sounds a bit similar to this thread with a workaround for version mismatch? https://elixirforum.com/t/no-response-from-ssh-sftp-list-dir-2-when-given-path-other-than-root/25130/5

Comment: @lossleader yes it is same issue, really helpful. thanks